# Resizing html scrollbars in native browser with no border

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, webkit

I have downloaded and run web-kit .net successfully.  I have set up a project using winforms, adding the web-kit dll.  I am looking to make a full html application from it, with some native functionality(printing etc).  The problem is, since the web window is the full screen, I am currently looking at how to re-size the window manually.

I can make code to trigger on click, so i put an image with a click even in the bottom right corner.  The problem is, the scroll-bars hide behind it(the down arrow, and the right arrow).  Is there a way to limit the area of the scroll-bars so the image isn't in the way?

Other solution are, of course, welcome.

---

I have the following as an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GsfJ9/

The scrollbar doesn't hit the bottom, but sadly, neither does the text.  I tried ensuring `overflow` was set to `visible`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Panel and put everything inside it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical"></asp:Panel>
```